# Array : store array in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

for example i have some element like below

```
<div class="1">abc,cbc</div>
<div class="1">GSV,SDG</div>
```

How can i  store it as below, an array in array format.

```
var new arr = [[abc,cbc],[GSV,SDG]]
```

Comment: Use `array.concat()` function. For example, `var firstArray = [5, 6];
var secondArray = [7, 8];
var newArray = firstArray.concat(secondArray);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `map` of jQuery. It helps you to create an `array` out of all selected elements. Just `return` the values you want to store in the resulting array.

Your class `1` is invalid. A class must start with `-`, `_` or `a-z`. So I renamed it for this example.

```js
var array = $("div.class1").map(function() {
    return [$(this).html().split(",")];
}).get();

console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">abc,cbc</div>
<div class="class1">GSV,SDG</div>
```

Comment: It might be better to use the specific class and not just the div-element.

Comment: Why do you need `.get()` at the end?

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko : to get result as an array otherwise it would be a jQuery object

Comment: You should considering that he's probably not looking for a jQuery solution.

Comment: The question is marked with `jQuery` @TyrionGraphiste. So what is your point here? Post a plain JS answer if you like to ...

Comment: Right, didn't see the tag.

Comment: *"Your class 1 is invalid"* That's incorrect. Classes can start with just about any non-whitespace character you want. But the CSS selector `.1` is invalid, which is a different thing, because the class name *in a selector* cannot start with an unescaped digit. `.\31` is a valid selector for `class="1"` elements (of course, in a string you have to escape the backslash: `".\\31"`). https://jsfiddle.net/8g7jvbLh/

Comment: Use pure JavaScript to implement it like [this](http://jsbin.com/palusa/edit?html,js,console).